# What is this up arrow after swiping up and down on an app in ios

Tags: ios

[image]

Here is a picture of the up arrow screen I mentioned. The app takes up the bottom half of the screen and on the top half there is an arrow pointing up. This happens whenever I swipe up and down without releasing on any app on ios. I am using an iPhone 11. After clicking the arrow the app returns to normal mode so I can't imagine what this is for. After doing some research it seems similar looking to the split screen feature on iPad OS, but I know ios doesn't have a split screen mode so I'm not sure.

#### Note:

Duolingo is completely irrelevant to this question. I just had to use an app to demonstrate the question and chose duolingo as it was the app I was on at the time

#### Edit:

It apparently does this on lock screen as well as apps.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this feature is to allow you to reach your entire screen with one hand. Just found [an article](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/reachability-iph145eba8e9/ios) about it from Apple. It can be turned off in the settings under **Settings** > **Accessibility** > **Touch**.